# Какова роль файла bootstrap-theme.min.css ?

Tags: bootstrap

Какова роль файла `bootstrap-theme.min.css` и в каком случае можно без него обойтись?

Answer (score 1):

**bootstrap-theme.css** — это готовая тема Bootstrap.

**bootstrap-theme.min.css** - это точно такие же файлы как **`bootstrap-theme.css`** только в сжатом виде (процентов на 30% меньше).

Подключение этого файла необязательно.

Comment: и все таки каково назначение этого файла?

Comment: bootstrap-theme.css - незначительно переопределяет внешний вид. Его можно использовать как основу для создания собственных тем.